# Mapping !! in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I am trying to map !! to a list i.e. have a list of positions and a list where I am trying to return the elements in these positions, so far I have:

```
map $ flip listOfThings!!listOfPositions
```

I think this is wrong, but cannot work out how to fix it! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I can't help feeling there must be a better way of doing this, because `!!` is a needlessly slow and non-list-ish way of doing things. How did you get your list of positions? Might you be able to use `filter` or something similar directly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
> map (['a', 'b', 'c']!!) [2, 1]

['c', 'b']
```